# Azure Worker Role - "TargetInvocationException" when starting in debug

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-roles

When attempting to run my WorkerRole project in debug (Visual Studio 2012), I am getting a 'TargetInvocationException' which is due to the fact that it can't find a required cfg file. Temporarily I have given all users full write access to C:\Users\johsmith\AppData\Local\dftmp but this has made no difference.

Any here is appreciated as I am rather stuck at the moment.

For reference, I am running Windows 8, VS2012 and the latest Azure SDK.

Here is the stack trace

```
 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.GetDebugListener()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.Initialize(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.Initialize(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.Worker.Loader.CreateConsoleRole(Parameters parameters)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.Worker.Loader.Main(String[] args)
```

The inner message is

```
{"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Users\\johsmith\\AppData\\Local\\dftmp\\deployment20(21)\\config\\deployment20(21).EventHandler.WorkerRoleWithSBQueue1_IN_0.1.cfg'."}



 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Runtime.DevelopmentFabricTraceListener.TryGetProviderGuid(Guid& ret)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Runtime.DevelopmentFabricTraceListener.Init()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working by uninstalling all 'Azure' related programs and re-installing the latest SDK. I noticed I had some older Azure SDK applications installed which may have been screwing something up.